# Jquery: how can I select cells from a table that contain a specified string of html?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to style some cells of a jquery-ui date picker based on application logic. I need to be able to scan through a table and select cells that contain a specified string of html. Here's an example table:

```
   <table class="ui-datepicker-calendar">
      <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="Sunday">Su</span></th>
         ...
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody><tr>
         <td class="ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month "> 1 </td>
         ...
      </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
```

How would I, say, scan through the table and select the cell containing "1" so that I could style it? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you saying you want *any* of the cells that contains the number one? As in 1, 10, 11, 12, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`beforeShowDay` event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShowDay) to add classes to a cell, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      return [true, date.getDate() === 1 ? 'color' : ''];
    },
    showOtherMonths: true
  });
});​
```

The second parameter in the array is any additional classes to add to the generated `<td>`.  Then just give it a style that matches, e.g.:

```
.color.ui-datepicker-other-month .ui-state-default { color: red; }​
```

[You can try out a quick demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/bBJXw/)

Comment: This works great, I really appreciate the help, but what if I want to do this onSelect?

Comment: @James - I don't quite follow...when you select the date picker goes away, or are you using one that always shows?

Comment: One that always shows. I would like to add a class to certain dates once one is selected.

Comment: @James - does it depend on which date it selected, or you know what you want to style before it's picked?

Comment: It depends on the date that's selected. Say, the selected day and the one afterward.